# Ask a problem on the Moore-Penrose inverse.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $\pi=(\pi_1,\cdots, \pi_h)^T$, where $\pi_i \geq 0$ for $i=1,\cdots,h$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^h=1$. Then

$$[\text{diag} (\pi)-\pi \pi^T]^\dagger = \text{diag}(\pi)^{-1}-1_p 1_p^T.$$

The Moore-Penrose inverse of a matrix is denoted by $A^\dagger$.

**Question 1:** is there any typo in $\sum\limits_{i=1}^h=1$? It doesn't make sense to me.

Proof: Because

$$\text{diag} (\pi)-\pi \pi^T=\text{diag} (\pi)^{1/2}[I_p-\text{diag} (\pi)^{-1/2} 
  \pi \pi^T \text{diag} (\pi)^{-1/2}]\text{diag} (\pi)^{1/2},$$

I can understand the above. **Question 2:** But I don't understand the next line:

we have

$$[\text{diag} (\pi)-\pi \pi^T]^\dagger = \text{diag} (\pi)^{-1/2} (I_p-\nu \nu^T)^\dagger \text{diag} (\pi)^{-1/2}$$

where $\nu =\text{diag} (\pi)^{-1/2}\pi$.

The remaining proof is:

[image]

Comment: Where is this being taken from?

Comment: @Deane the book Sufficient Dimension Reduction Methods and Applications with R, Section 4.3.

Comment: Regarding question 1, I suspect it should say $\sum_{i=1}^h \pi_i = 1$

Comment: The line you refer to in question two is strange. It looks like the author is implying some general result along the lines of 
$$
[PAP]^{\dagger} = P^{-1}A^\dagger P^{-1}
$$
for positive definite $P$ and positive semidefinite matrix $A$, but this result does not generally seem to hold. In fact, this result seems to be true if and only if $AA^\dagger$ commutes with $P$. That is, it is true if and only if the image of $A$ is an invariant subspace of $P$. Otherwise, $[PAP][ P^{-1}A^\dagger P^{-1}]$ fails to be symmetric.

Comment: Also, are $h$ and $p$ supposed to be the same number?

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes, h and p must be the same. Because in the remaining proof, the authors use $\pi^T 1_p=1$. So h and p must match.

Comment: There is something off about your textbook because the suggested formula does not seem to be correct (except in the case where $\pi = (1,\dots,1)/p$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula suggested in your textbook is apparently incorrect. For one thing, we can see that the pseudoinverse has the incorrect nullspace: the pseudoinverse of a symmetric matrix should have the same nullspace as the original. However, $1_p$ is in the nullpace of the original matrix since
$$
[\operatorname{diag}(\pi) - \pi\pi^T]1_p = \operatorname{diag}(\pi)1_p - \pi(\pi^T1_p) = \pi - \pi = 0,
$$
but for the suggested pseudoinverse we compute
$$
[\operatorname{diag}(\pi)^{-1} - 1_p1_p^T]1_p = \operatorname{diag}(\pi)^{-1}1_p - 1_p (1_p^T1_p) = \pi^{-1} - p1_p,
$$
where the entries of $\pi^{-1}$ are $\pi_j^{-1}$ for $j = 1,\dots,p$. We can see that $\pi^{-1} - p1_p = 0$ will hold if and only if $\pi$ is the uniform distribution, which is to say that $\pi = 1_p/p$.

---

As a specific counterexample, take $\pi = (1/4,1/4,1/2)$. We have
$$
\operatorname{diag}(\pi) - \pi\pi^T = 
\frac 1{16}
\pmatrix{3 & -1 & -2\\
1 & 3 & -2\\
-2 & -2 & 4}.
$$
Following the formula, the predicted pseudoinverse would be
$$
[\operatorname{diag}(\pi) - \pi\pi^T]^\dagger = \text{diag}(\pi)^{-1}-1_p 1_p^T \\
= \pmatrix{4&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&2} - \pmatrix{1 &1 & 1\\1 & 1 & 1\\1 & 1 & 1}\\
= \pmatrix{3 & -1 & -1\\
-1 & 1 & -1\\
-1 & -1 & 1}.
$$
However, the correct result seems to be
$$
[\operatorname{diag}(\pi) - \pi\pi^T]^\dagger = 
\frac 29 \pmatrix{
11 & -7 & -4\\
-7 & 11 & -4\\
-4 & -4 & 8}.
$$

Comment: Excellent answer, but do you have the proof of the  Moore-Penrose inverse of a symmetric matrix have the same nullspace as the original? If you don't mind, I can open a new question and then you can answer there.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4833998/prove-that-the-moore-penrose-inverse-of-a-symmetric-matrix-have-the-same-nullspa